# iFractals MLQ5 usage not understood

Tags: trading, indicator, mql5, metatrader5

Here is the code that I thought and tried. I thought that it was the right way to buy and sell for the Fractals signals. But getting buy and sell signals simultaneously.

```
  double UP[],DOWN[];
  double fractal_output = iFractals(_Symbol,_Period); 
  ArraySetAsSeries(UP,true);
  ArraySetAsSeries(DOWN,true); 
  CopyBuffer(fractal_output,0,0,5,UP);
  CopyBuffer(fractal_output,1,0,5,DOWN);
  if (UP[1])
  {
      Comment("BUY");
      trade.Buy(0.1);
  }
  if (DOWN[1])
  {
      Comment("SELL");
      trade.Sell(0.1);
  }
```

I don't understand how I can plan to buy and sell using the `iFractals` function indicator in my MQL5. What improvements need to be done?

Comment: Please give reason for the downvote.

Comment: Please understand that the person who down voted will most likely never see your comment.

Answer (score 2):

A `double fractal_output` should be **`int`** **not** `double` and initialized in the **`OnInit(){...}`** just once, **not** each tick.

Make sure you understand which fractal is obtained when accessing `UP[1]` - it seems to be 0,1,2,3,4 (left to right), so you are asking for fractal 3 bars before the current Bar.

Alternatively you can get a value before the current Bar (most probably it is zero until next bar after current starts).

Make sure that you have copied the buffer correctly (it is possible that it is not copied and `UP[1]` may throw `out-of-range error` - for that reason `CopyBuffer` returns a number of elements actually copied (so `if CopyBuffer()!=5){print();return;}`)

What do you expect to see when calling `if(UP[1]){}` ?

A buffer might take both positive values and `EMPTY_VALUE (== 2^31-1)`.

It is better to check the value of the buffer: `if(UP[i]>0){}` or `if(UP[i]!=EMPTY_VALUE){...}`

Do not forget about a special case, when some candle has both an upper and a lower fractal - What to do in that corner-case?

It will open a Long and then open a Short (so it may close the Buy by opening a Short).

Probably you need check the open orders before that or open bar - otherwise you'll have many positions opened during one candle.

Tester will help you find other problems that you could miss when planning the EA.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It is helpful a bit. But can you please show me how is it possible to design EA with `iFractals`? Just for an example so I can understand what I can do. I am doing this for personal purpose so I will know the working of fractals in buying and selling. And when there is a case of up and down at the same time.. it should do nothing.. I guess you can help me.

Comment: look at the examples of EA in MQL5. Experts\Examples\Moving Average\Moving Average.mq5. Keep in mind they check everything on open bar `(rt[1].tick>1 -> return;)`. replace MA with fractals and print fractals to see values and make sure this is what you need.